# Sorting within CosmosDB based on different parameters

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, azure-cosmosdb

I have a problem where it comes to custom sorting.

I need to sort elements based on 3 factors:

1. ID (string)
2. Flag (boolen)
3. Date (datetime

Example fiddle code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OSicuK

Sample data records:

```html
{
            "id": "cbb440a8-fc26-4d30-966c-eba114410c6b",
            "creationDate": "2021-05-25T00:00:00",
            "child": false,
            "parentId": "cbb440a8-fc26-4d30-966c-eba114410c6b"
        },
        {
            "id": "cf70fbef-aa4f-45d3-96ab-3e211c290765",
            "creationDate": "2021-05-27T00:00:00",
            "child": true,
            "parentId": "cbb440a8-fc26-4d30-966c-eba114410c6b"
        },
        {
            "id": "48a82712-3e72-3ca7-a02d-edafd170f0b5",
            "creationDate": "2021-06-17T00:00:00",
            "child": false,
            "parentId": "48a82712-3e72-3ca7-a02d-edafd170f0b5"
        },
        {   (this one should be ealier since creationDate is ealier than one above and both child is set to false)
            "id": "1e4372f9-54dd-45b1-a401-56accbefc936", 
            "creationDate": "2021-05-25T00:00:00",
            "child": false,
            "parentId": "1e4372f9-54dd-45b1-a401-56accbefc936"
        },
        {
            "id": "cf70fbef-aa4f-45d3-96ab-3e211c290765",
            "creationDate": "2021-05-27T00:00:00",
            "child": true,
            "parentId": "1e4372f9-54dd-45b1-a401-56accbefc936"
        },
        {
            "id": "82d7ea62-8f30-4bfd-be27-eb79c0f5e9e9",
            "creationDate": "2021-05-27T00:00:00",
            "child": true,
            "parentId": "1e4372f9-54dd-45b1-a401-56accbefc936"
        },
        {
            "id": "48a82712-3e72-3ca7-a02d-edafd170f0b5",
            "creationDate": "2021-06-17T00:00:00",
            "child": true,
            "parentId": "1e4372f9-54dd-45b1-a401-56accbefc936"
        }
```

Records need to be sorted from oldest parent to the newest, when child flag is set to false  then record needs to be before all records with the same parentId but child flag set to true.

I've tried following:

`return documents .OrderBy(x => x.parentId) .ThenBy(x => x.child) .ThenBy(x => x.creationDate);`

Unfortunately CreationDate is not sorted correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is sorted by parentId first, since it is a guid, so the creationDate does not matter anymore, I guess.

Comment: Exactly it doesnt! But at the end I need to take CreationDate into considiration and dunno how

Comment: remove all other orderby, only use the date, see whether it is ordered?

Comment: You're missing a point, check please example result.
Records need to be sorted from oldest parent to the newest, when child flag is set to false then record needs to be before all records with the same parentId but child flag set to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is the grouping of data.

Without grouping you can either sort on `ParentId` or on `CreationDate`, but you want to sort the parents with their children (ie grouped), in the order of the parents' `CreationDate`.

```
var results = list
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Child)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ParentId)
    .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing can be resolved by changing the sorting order. You can use `OrderByDescending` instead of `OrderBy`.

Below is the sample code:-

```
return documents.OrderByDescending(x => x.parentId).ThenBy(x =>
 x.child).ThenBy(x => x.creationDate);
```

Comment: Unfortunetelly it doesn't solve it. Still some parents are before others which have later creation date. Plus how would that work when I would like to have Descending order by Parent date?

I've attached result that came from your example to the main question

Comment: @Krzysztof Thanks for the feedback. I have used sample data shared by you and was able to achieve the expected result as mentioned in question using the code. Did I miss something in my understanding?
Here is screenshot of result.
https://i.imgur.com/6q38v2y.png

Comment: thanks for the response! The only difference is that Id is string not Guid(since its being kept in CosmosDB). The way your data sort is correct, but when you are sorting by GUID it doesnt take creation date into considiration so I believe your outcome is luck :D Please check the data I posted as invalid.

Comment: I've created fiddle with an example, guess that will be easier :D 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/OSicuK